# Upload extracts of text files

Tags: java, javascript, html, file-upload, applet

I am looking for a way for clients to upload a piece of a plain text file from within their browsers.

The situation is as follows: We have a pipeline that needs to work on only a small piece of a large data file that users will upload. We want to not upload the entire file but rather, on client side, extract from their local file the relevant data, and upload only that.

As far as I am aware, this cannot happen via JavaScript, or any new HTML-5 features, for security reasons. Its possible to upload the entire file, but not cut it up, and extract pieces to upload.

The reading I have done makes me think the only way to do what we want is via a Java applet.
I have found lots of Java Applets (eg: http://jupload.sourceforge.net ), but these don't let me extract pieces of a file.

Any suggestions of where I could find how to extract a piece of a file would be appreciated.

Note, this is not asking about how to upload a file, or about slicing up a file and uploading all of the resulting slices. Both of those I have found solutions to.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is possible using just pure JavaScript with the help of the FileReader API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader

I used it to resize jpegs (either with canvas or webgl) and reinject the EXIF data into the resized images before uploading them.